# Cloudant Custom Sort

Tags: couchdb, ibm-cloud, cloudant, python-cloudant, nosql

I have my data as follows

```
{
    "key":"adasd",
    "col1"::23, 
    "col2":3
}
```

I want to see the results sorted in descending order of the ratio of `col1/sum(col2)`

where `sum(col2)` refers to the `sum` of **all** values of `col2`. I am a bit new to cloudant so I don't know what the best way to approach this is. I can think of a few options.

1. Create a new column for `sum(col2)` and keep updating it with each new value of `col2`
2. For each record,also create a new column `col1/sum(col2)`. Then i can sort on this column.
3. Use *Views* to calculate the ratio and sum on the fly. This way I don't have to store new columns plus I don't have to perform costly calculations on each update.

I tried to create a view and the map function is easy enough

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc._id, {"col1_value":doc.col1,"col2_value":doc.col2});
}
```

but I am confused by the reduce template

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
  if (rereduce) {
    return sum(values);
  } else {
    return values.length;
  }
}
```

I have no idea on how to access the values of the two columns and then aggregate here. Is this even possible? Is there any other way to achieve the result I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two comments:

1. Ordering by `X/sum(Y)` is the same as ordering by `X` (or by `-X` if `sum(Y)` is negative).  So for ordering purposes, just order by `X` and save yourself a bunch of hassle.
2. Assuming you actually want to know the value of `X/sum(Y)`, and not just order by it, there's no one-step way to accomplish this in CouchDB.  The best I can think of is to create a map/reduce view that gives you the global `sum(Y)`.  Then you can fetch that sum with a simple query, and do the math in your application, when fetching your documents.

Comment: yes, thanks. how should i create the view to calculate sum(Y)?

Comment: I suggest reading up on views and map/reduce functions. Some suggested starting points:  [here](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views), [here](http://www.ramblingincode.com/building-a-couchdb-reduce-function/) and [here](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions).